# Quadratic variation of integral of martingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, quadratic-variation

I have a question regarding the quadratic variation of a martingale. Assume for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a martingale $(M_t(x))_{t \geq 0}$ with known quadratic variation $\langle M(x) \rangle _t$. Assume $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a sufficiently smooth function and rapidly decreasing at $\infty$, such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is finite and well-defined for all 'nicely behaved' continuous real valued functions $f$ (I skip some details here, the main part is that one doesn't have to worry about convergence of integrals in that question).

First, I want to verify $(\int_{\mathbb{R}}M_t(x)\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x)_{t \geq 0}$ is a martingale. Is it true under the above assumptions? I am not sure how to formalize this, so any help will be greatly appreciated. I belive it requires using the Fubini's theorem, but I am not sure how to justify its use here.

Second, after verifying the above I want to calculate the quadratic variation of the above martingale. That is, I want to calculate $\langle\int_{\mathbb{R}}M_{(\cdot)}(x)\phi(x)\mathrm{d}x \rangle _t$ in terms of $\langle M(x) \rangle _t$ and $\phi$. Here I really have know idea what to do. Again, any suggestion will be great.

Comment: Do there exist non-trivial smooth functions $\phi$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \phi(x) dx$ is finite and well-defined for all measurable $f$?  That's not obvious to me...it seems like if $\phi$ is positive on some interval, you could define $f$ to be something like $\frac 1x$ on that interval.

Comment: Well, you are right. I didn't want to elaborate on the details of the assumptions, since they are not really relevant. The most important part is that the integrals in the question are well defined and finite, and one doesn't have to worry about that. I edited accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, yes, this is a martingale.  This only requires that $\int \mathbb{E}[|M_t(x)|] |\phi(x)| dx < \infty$ for all $t$.  Then, by Fubini's theorem,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \int M_t(x) \phi(x) dx \mid \mathcal F_s \right] &= \int \mathbb{E}[M_t(x)|\mathcal F_s] \phi(x) dx  \\
&= \int M_s(x) \phi(x) dx .
\end{align*}
If you're a little skeptical of using Fubini's theorem with conditional expectation, I'll put a proof that it's valid at the end.

Now we will compute the quadratic variation.  For notational convenience, let $X_t := \int M_t(x) \phi(x) dx$.  By the definition of quadratic variation,
\begin{align*}
\langle X,X \rangle_t &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n (X_{t_{k+1}}-X_{t_k})^2
\end{align*}
For a given partition $(t_0,...,t_n)$ of $[0,t]$, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n (X_{t_{k+1}}-X_{t_k})^2 &= \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \int M_{t_{k+1}}(x) \phi(x) dx - \int M_{t_k}(x) \phi(x) dx \right)^2 \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \int \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(x) - M_{t_k}(x)\big) \phi(x) dx \right)^2 \\
&=  \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \int \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(x) - M_{t_k}(x)\big) \phi(x) dx \right)\left( \int \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(y) - M_{t_k}(y)\big) \phi(y) dy \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \int \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(x) - M_{t_k}(x)\big) \phi(x) dx \right)\left( \int \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(y) - M_{t_k}(y)\big) \phi(y) dy \right) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \int \int \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(x) - M_{t_k}(x)\big) \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(y) - M_{t_k}(y)\big) \phi(y) \phi(x) dx dy \\
&= \int \int  \sum_{k=0}^n \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(x) - M_{t_k}(x)\big) \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(y) - M_{t_k}(y)\big) \phi(y) \phi(x) dx dy.
\end{align*}

Now, assuming everything is well-behaved enough that we can exchange the limits with the integrals, we have

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int \int  \sum_{k=0}^n \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(x) - M_{t_k}(x)\big) \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(y) - M_{t_k}(y)\big) \phi(y) \phi(x) dx dy \\
&= \int \int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{k=0}^n \left( \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(x) - M_{t_k}(x)\big) \big(M_{t_{k+1}}(y) - M_{t_k}(y)\big) \right)\phi(y) \phi(x) dx dy \\
&= \int \int \langle M(x),M(y) \rangle_t \phi(y) \phi(x) dx dy,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\langle X,X \rangle_t &= \int \int \langle M(x),M(y) \rangle_t \phi(y) \phi(x) dx dy.
\end{align*}
The quadratic covariation of $\int M_t(x) \phi(x)dx$ unfortunately requires the cross-variation $\langle M(x),M(y) \rangle_t$ rather than just the quadratic variation.

---

Proof of conditional Fubini's theorem:  Let $A \in \mathcal F_s$.  Then, by Fubini's theorem,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int M_t(x) \phi(x) dx 1_A \right] &= \int \mathbb{E}[ M_t(x)1_A] \phi(x) dx  \\
&= \int \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[M_t(x)|\mathcal F_s]1_A] \phi(x) dx  \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\int \mathbb{E}[M_t(x)|\mathcal F_s] \phi(x) dx 1_A \right].
\end{align*}
Since this holds for arbitrary $A \in \mathcal F_s$, we conclude
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\int M_t(x) \phi(x) dx \mid \mathcal F_s \right] &= \int \mathbb{E}[M_t(x)|\mathcal F_s] \phi(x) dx.
\end{align*}

Comment: It may be simple, but how do you get that $X_t$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable? Is it a well-known result that the integral of measurable functions is measurable? It sounds correct, but I didn't manage to prove that.

Comment: @Eran That's a good point that I hadn't considered...it would probably be best to ask that as a separate question, though.  It likely requires some additional assumptions such as $x \mapsto M_t(x)$ is measurable for all $t$.